# Where did the Markdown Preview button go in VS Code 1.3.0?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code 1.2.0, I was loving the [Markdown preview button](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown) in the top-right corner of each editor view, which allowed me to quickly create a live preview of my Markdown document (by clicking the *Split View* button and then the *Preview* button).

Screenshot of *Preview* button, highlighted in red:

[image]
<sup>[img source](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/markdown-preview-in-visual-studio-code/)</sup>

Now in 1.3.0, the preview button is no longer there, and the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/June_2016) make no mention of its removal. The notes do mention a [new *Open Preview* context menu](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/June_2016#_extension-authoring) (listed as a workaround below). I also found an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8996) for this problem with no response (yet).

The only workarounds for *Preview* on OS X I found were:

- Option 1: Right-click the file in the lefthand list panel, and choose **Open Preview**.
- Option 2: Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> while on the editor.

But these workarounds are inconvenient for me, and I much prefer the previous workflow. How can I restore the preview button (or equivalent clickable solution)?

**UPDATE** Another option suggested by @BenjaminPasero:

- Option 3: Right-click the file's tab, and choose **Open Preview**, which opens the preview in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BenjaminPasero indicated in [his GitHub comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8996#issuecomment-231543763), the preview button could be restored by disabling the new `showTabs` feature:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to open settings.
2. In `settings.json`, add this option:

   ```
   // Controls if opened editors should show in tabs or not.
   "workbench.editor.showTabs": false
   ```

Comment: But what if I want my tabs untouched?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we ran out of time to find a good solution for the editor actions (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7666). We plan to address this for July. Meanwhile you find this action in the context menu of a tab or via the global command that you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking forward to the fix. Hopefully, it will be as simple as before, and not require multiple clicks. :-)